# Postgresql improving access efficiency

Tags: python, sql, performance, postgresql

I created a postgres table which looks like:

```
name   ID   SNO
jack   12   1
bob    123  2
andy   34   3
jack   23   4
```

etc. It has a total of 41 million entries. SNO is my primary key of continuous INT values. When I run a query to select a particular SNO, it works lightning fast. However! My need is to run the query on 'name' which should return all instances of a particular name. Note that names need not be unique and are most likely repeated but with different ID's. A query to search for a name takes way to long to find. I tried creating an index on 'name' using this:

```
CREATE INDEX name ON userlist(name)
```

However, while this improves performance, it is still way too slow. Is there any way that I can index 'name' which is a 'text' data type to improve access performance as much as accessing the 'int' SNO?

Comment: What is the datatype of name? Also, can you post an explain plan of querying using the name field?

Comment: name is in data type "text" as in: CREATE TABLE userlist(name text, id text, SNO number)

Comment: Please upload the execution plan (ideally with `explain analyze`) to http://explain.depesz.com  and post the link here.

Comment: You might also be interested in this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Dropped my table accidentally.. Re-creating it.. Will post the explain analyze asap

Comment: Start with posting a typical query (would be included in explain analyze). Table definition would help, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make enough space for the index in memory. The `shared_buffers` setting can be helpful in this.